# In general, are subsets of recursively enumerable sets recursive sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computability

I recently became interested in the solution to Hilbert's tenth problem, in reading about the succession of results that lead up to the proof I came across the notion of recursive sets  and recursively enumerable sets. The distinction between the two sets is very subtle. I need some help in answering the question in the title.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are recursive and recursively enumerable mean the same?

Comment: You wrote :"The distinction between the two sets is very subtle." For a recursive set $A\subseteq \mathbb N,$ there is an algorithm that, given any $n\in\mathbb N,$ tells you whether $n\in A$ or $n\notin A.$ For a recursively enumerable set $A\subseteq\mathbb N,$ there is an algorithm that, given any $n\in\mathbb N,$ ultimately stops running if $n\in A$ and runs forever if $n\notin A.$ If it's been running for a trillion years, you don't know whether it will run forever or halt in the next minute. Clearly $A$ is recursive if and only if $A$ and $\mathbb N\smallsetminus A$ are$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$recursively enumerable. That some recursively enumerable sets are not recursive was shown in the 1930s. That proposition is crucial to understanding something like Hilbert's tenth problem.

Comment: So no, they're definitely not the same. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Note that $\Bbb N$ is recursively enumerable. But since there are only countably many Turing machines, there are only countably many recursively enumerable sets, on the other hand there are uncountably many subsets to $\Bbb N$. So most sets are not recursively enumerable.

The same argument applies to every infinite RE set.

Comment: On the other hand, every nonempty r.e. set contains a nonempty recursive subset: Suppose $A$ is r.e. If $A$ is finite, we are done. Otherwise, consider an algorithm that lists $A$, and only prints out numbers in increasing order as they are listed: Say that the algorithm lists $7,22,1,3,14,6,50,\dots$; then we would only list $7,22,50,\dots$ The resulting subset of $A$ is listed in increasing order, and is therefore recursive.

Comment: @Andres: Non-empty recursive subset, of course. :-)

Comment: ${}$Of course. :-)

Comment: That is, recursively enumerable sets contain recursive subsets, however it is not the case that every subset is a recursive set. This is what I understand.( @asaf, @andres)

Comment: @Genomeme: Yes, that is true.

Comment: @Genomeme Yes, exactly. There is a fair amount of recent, active work on Hilbert's tenth problem and its extensions, by the way. very interesting topic.